# HTC One M7 use Sense 5.5 app in Sense 6?

Tags: htc-sense

I updated to Sense 6, but to be honest I'm regretting it. The colors changed, the icon dock now feels too blended together, but whatever, I can deal with this.

What I can't deal with, is the native camera app. I want to use the camera app that came with 5.5 (with dual buttons for photo/video, instead of having to click a menu to choose whichever you want).

I tried extracting the Camera.apk from the ROM, but it fails to install.

I'm not on a rooted device.

Is there ANY way to have the camera app that was in sense 5.5 on sense 6?..

Thanks..